# Repeat rows and generate a new column accordingly in dplyr

Tags: r, row, repeat, dplyr

I have a dataset like **countries_not_appear_indices**

```
countries_not_appear_indices <- as.data.frame(c("CUW", "ARM", "VGB", "ATG", "KNA", "GRD", "VCT", "LCA", "TCA", "GNB", "GNQ", "CYM", "MNE", "MDV", "MKD", "GIB", "LIE", "COM", "NCL", "BES", "PYF")) %>%
  rename(iso = `c("CUW", "ARM", "VGB", "ATG", "KNA", "GRD", "VCT", "LCA", "TCA", "GNB", "GNQ", "CYM", "MNE", "MDV", "MKD", "GIB", "LIE", "COM", "NCL", "BES", "PYF")`) %>%
  mutate(ie = 0, ih = 0)
```

and I want to repeat each observation 11 times (one time for each month). So we have something like **countries_not_appear_indices_panel**

```
iso <- c("CUW", "CUW", "CUW", "CUW", "CUW", "CUW", "CUW", "CUW", "CUW", "CUW", "CUW", "CUW", "ARM", "ARM", "ARM", "ARM", "ARM", "ARM", "ARM", "ARM", "ARM", "ARM", "ARM", "ARM")
month <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
ie <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
ih <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

countries_not_appear_indices_panel <- data.frame(iso, month, ie, ih)
```

To repeat each column I did try:

```
countries_not_appear_indices[rep(seq_len(nrow(countries_not_appear_indices)), each = 12), ]
```

However, I also have to generate the month function in the correct way.

Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `uncount` to repeat each row 12 times and create month column using `row_number()` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

countries_not_appear_indices %>%
  uncount(12) %>%
  group_by(iso) %>%
  mutate(month = row_number(), .after = 'iso') %>%
  ungroup 

#   iso   month    ie    ih
#   <chr> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 CUW       1     0     0
# 2 CUW       2     0     0
# 3 CUW       3     0     0
# 4 CUW       4     0     0
# 5 CUW       5     0     0
# 6 CUW       6     0     0
# 7 CUW       7     0     0
# 8 CUW       8     0     0
# 9 CUW       9     0     0
#10 CUW      10     0     0
# … with 242 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this in `base R`

```
new <- countries_not_appear_indices[rep(seq_len(nrow(countries_not_appear_indices)), 12),]
new$month <-  with(new, ave(seq_along(iso), iso, FUN = seq_along))
```